# JavaScript regex to remove variable from query

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove a variable from a query string. This is my current approach:

```
var str = "http://example.com/tal.php?sec=16&name=xxxx&size=xxxx";
str = str.replace(/([&])name=.*?(&|$)/g,"");
```

There are two problems with this code:

- Both the `&` at the beginning of name and at the end get removed. I'd like only one to be removed
- It should also work when the variable name is at the beginning or at the end of the query string.

How can I tell the regex to delete the second `&` only if it has matched the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using capturing groups and then using them in the callback function to re-insert the `&` character appropriately:

```
([?&])name=.*?($|&)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG4xV4/2)

Here is a JavaScript snippet showing replacement process in all the 3 positions:

```js
function removeQueryArg(str) {
  var re = /([?&])name=.*?($|&)/; 
  return str.replace(re, function(m, grp1, grp2, offset, input) {
     return grp1 === "?" ? "?" : (grp2 === "&" ? "&" : "");
  });
}

document.write(removeQueryArg('http://example.com/tal.php?name=xxxx&sec=16&size=xxxx') + "<br/>" +
   removeQueryArg('http://example.com/tal.php?sec=16&name=xxxx&size=xxxx') + "<br/>" +
   removeQueryArg('http://example.com/tal.php?sec=16&size=xxxx&name=xxxx'));
```

Let me explain:

- The `([?&])name=.*?($|&)` regex contains 2 capturing groups `([?&])` (matching either `?` or `&`) and `($|&)` (matching end of string or `&`).
- Inside the `replace` method, we can pass the contents of these groups to the callback function where we can further analyze what to do with the replacement.
- `function(m, grp1, grp2, offset, input)` actually uses the whole match `m`, and `grp1` and `grp2` are the captured texts. `offset` (match index in the original string) and `input` (the whole input string) are not used here, but they might turn out useful some day.
- In the callback, I am checking if group 1 is equal to "?". If yes, the argument is in the beginning of the query string, and we need to restore the `?` in front.
- If not, we need to check the contents of the 2nd group. If it is equal to `&`, the match is in the middle of the query string, we need to add `&`. If not, we are at the end, do not add anything, we remove the whole match.

See more at [*Specifying a function as a parameter* at MDN `replace` method help page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Comment: I made a correction, as I don't really want to match the first "?",  after this change, if you put the variable as first of the querystring, it doesn't get matched...

Comment: True, all this can be solved with capturing groups and logic inside a callback function. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Looks good bu I don't understand what the function you give to replace is doing...

Comment: Is it now clearer? Callback functions are very handy in JS as its regex engine is one of the poorest.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve this is to delete the `name` parameter together with the question mark or ampersand that precedes it. If the question mark gets deleted, put it back in by replacing the first ampersand with a question mark.

```
s = s.replace(/([?&]name=[^&]*)/, '');
if (s.indexOf('?') == -1) {
  s = s.replace(/[&]/, '?');
}
```

Demonstration:

```js
function print(s) {
  document.write(s + '<br \>');
}

function deleteName(s) {
  print(s);
  s = s.replace(/([?&]name=[^&]*)/, '');
  if (s.indexOf('?') == -1) {
    s = s.replace(/[&]/, '?');
  }
  print(s);
  print('');
}

deleteName('http://example.com/tal.php?name=xxxx&sec=16&size=xxxx');

deleteName('http://example.com/tal.php?sec=16&name=xxxx&size=xxxx');

deleteName('http://example.com/tal.php?sec=16&size=xxxx&name=xxxx');
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, basically, this is an similar solution, but using 2 regexp replacements instead of one.

Comment: `<br \>` is a valid tag.